# Defined a order on Z such that every subset has a upper bound.

Tags: analysis

How can I defined an a order on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that every subset has a upper bound.

Comment: do you have any ideas so far?

Comment: I was thinking in something like this: Define $f$:$\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)$=$\dfrac{-1}{x+\pi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy, concrete example: define $m\preceq n$ if and only if $|m|>|n|$, or $|m|=|n|$ and $m<n$. This gives you the linear order

$$\ldots,-3,3,-2,2,-1,1,0\;.$$

This is the reverse of a well-order, so every non-empty subset actually has a largest element. Specifically, if $\varnothing\ne S\subseteq\Bbb Z$, let $m=\min\{|n|:n\in\S\}$; if $m\in S$, then $m$ is the largest member of $S$, and if $m\notin S$, then $-m$ is the largest member of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a linear order downwards from a maximal element.  Take the reverse order on $\Bbb N$, which does what you need, and biject $\Bbb Z$ with it in any way you please.   The maximal element might be $29$ and the one below that $802358$. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most trivial comes from the ordinals and is related the the comment under the post.

Basically, we are going to move $1$ to $\infty$ and leave all the other points alone. That is, let $a < 1$ for all integers $a \neq 1$ and let $a < b$ if $b - a$ is positive and $a, b \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ordering such that any subset has a *least* upper bound:

Let $f : \Bbb{Z} \mapsto \Bbb{Q} \cap [-1,+1]$ map $$0 \mapsto 0\\ n \in \Bbb{Z}^+ = \sum_{i=0}^k b_i 2^i : b_k = 1 \wedge \forall i, b_i \in \{0,1\} \mapsto \frac12 \sum_{i=0}^k b_i 2^{-i} \\ n \in \Bbb{Z}^- = -\sum_{i=0}^k b_i 2^i : b_k = 1 \wedge \forall i, b_i \in \{0,1\} \mapsto -\frac12 \sum_{i=0}^k b_i 2^{-i}
$$
This is just saying that $f(n)$ is obtained by expressing $n$ in binary, and writing a binary "decimal" using the bits of $n$ in reverse order; for example $f(6) = 0.011 = \frac38$.  Now define the order relation to be 
$$
n < m \Longleftrightarrow f(n) < f(m)
$$

Since the range of $f(n)$ is a subset of the real interval $[-1,+1]$ and is thus bounded, every subset of values of $f(n)$ has a least upper bound (which may or may not be in the subset).  Therefore, under this ordering, every subset of $\Bbb{Z}$ has a least upper bound.